# По какому правилу ставим запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Я должен признать, эта идея прекрасна.

По какому правилу мы ставим запятую в данном предложении?

Answer (score 1):

***Я должен признать, эта идея прекрасна.***

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), отношения между двумя частями **изъяснительные.** В этом случае классическим знаком является **двоеточие**, но запятая тоже допускается.

**Розенталь**, [§ 44. Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150) (пункт 3):

**Примечание.** При отсутствии **оттенка предупреждения** в начале бессоюзного сложного предложения данного типа после первой части вместо двоеточия ставится запятая: *Слышу, земля задрожала* (Н.).

**Оттенок предупреждения** — это увеличенная предупредительная пауза с неполным понижением тона перед ней.

Такой вариант отчасти (по семантике и интонации) соответствует **вводному предложению**.